# UIView transitionWithView custom animation option

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

I have an application that first displays a login screen. Once the user logs in, this code is executed:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view.window
                              duration:0.7
                               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                            animations:^{
                                self.view.window.rootViewController = menuController;
                            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                // Code to run after animation

                            }];
```

This works as expected; however, I would like to define my own custom animation option instead of the flip from left/right option.

A simple example would be sliding the new view controller onto the screen from top to bottom. How can I do this when changing the rootViewController?

Also, is there a completely different approach to animate switching the rootViewController? I am not married to this solution, it is just the closest thing I can find through Google/SO search.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using a `CATransition` should be able to give you the sort of animation you're looking for. Granted, I've never actually attempted this specifically with `rootViewController`, but to slide the view in from top to bottom, I'd suggest trying this:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 1.0;
transition.type = kCATransitionFromBottom;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFade;

CALayer *layer = self.view.window.rootViewController.view.layer;
[layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
```

Answer (score 0):

For that change to happen you must first add the **ViewController and its view to the parent viewController**. A simple trick could be add it "on the roof" of your window   (starting Y position = -self.view.bounds.size.height). And then use

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:
                      delay:
                    options:
                 animations:^{}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     self.view.window.rootViewController = menuController;
                 }];
```

Then simply inside the animation brackets create the animation you want.